# Are there smooth bodies of constant width?

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, constant-width

The standard Reuleaux triangle is not smooth, but the three
points of tangential discontinuity can be smoothed as
in the figure below (left), from [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_of_constant_width).
However, it is unclear (to me) from this diagram
whether the curve is $C^2$ or $C^\infty$.

*Meissner’s tetrahedron* is a 3D body of constant width,
but it is not smooth, as is evident in the right figure
below.

[image: Constant Width]

My question is:

> Are there $C^\infty$ constant-width bodies in $\mathbb{R}^d$ (other than the spheres)?

The image of Meissner’s tetrahedron above is taken
from [the impressive work](http://www.lama.univ-savoie.fr/%7Elachand/Spheroforms.html) of
Thomas Lachand–Robert and Edouard Oudet,
"Bodies of constant width in arbitrary dimension"
(*Math. Nachr.* 280, No. 7, 740-750 (2007); [pre-publication PDF here](http://www.lama.univ-savoie.fr/%7Elachand/pdfs/spheroforms.pdf)). Here is a [link to Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20170425084009/http://www.lama.univ-savoie.fr/%7Elachand/Spheroforms.html).)

I suspect the answer to my question is known, in which case a reference would suffice.  Thanks!

**Addendum.**
Thanks to the knowledgeable (and rapid!) answers by Gerry, Anton, and Andrey,
my question is completely answered—I am grateful!!

Comment: I trust you mean, other than the sphere. 

Comment: @Gerry: Yes, that's what I meant, thanks; updated the question.

Comment: You ask whether the curve on the diagram is smooth.  It isn't: it's made from six circle arcs.


Comment: Thanks, Zsbán. So I guess just $C^1$?

Comment: The construction by three non-incident straight lines & circle arcs, is the simplest, but not the unique way to make figures with constant width; the same works of course with 4 or more lines. The continuous version as well, and allows smooth objects, in any dimension $d$ (less immediate for $d>2$).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Fillmore showed that there are sets of constant width in $\mathbb R^d$ with analytic boundaries which have a trivial symmetry group (so these are very different from spheres;
see ["Symmetries of surfaces of constant width"](https://doi.org/0.4310/jdg/1214428822),  *J. Differential Geom.*, Vol 3, (1969),  pp. 103-110).

Moreover, the set of bodies of constant width with analytic boundaries is dense in the space of all convex bodies of constant width in $\mathbb R^d$ with respect to the Hausdorff metric (see e.g. ["Smooth approximation of convex bodies"](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02844505) by Schneider).

Comment: In the second paragraph, a "of constant width" is missing; it is implicit, but it disturbed me for a second.

Comment: For an ignoramus like me, these results are quite impressive and highly counter-intuitive.

Comment: I took a look at the Fillmore paper, and just before his Corollary to Theorem 2 -- which reads 

"Corollary. There exists an analytic hypersurface of constant width in E^n having the same group of symmetries as a regular n-simplex."

-- he writes "If we imitate the construction of a Reuleux triangle . . .. Thus:"

This seems to imply that he is assuming that [the intersection of four balls in 3-space, centered at the vertices of a regular tetrahedron and each with radius = the side-length of the tetrahedron] is a body of constant width.

But this is known to be false.

Answer (score 26):

Take any odd $C^\infty$-function $f$ on the sphere.
Consider the convex set 
$$R_\epsilon=\{\,x\in\mathbb R^n\mid\langle x,u\rangle\le 1+\epsilon{\cdot}f(u)\ \ \text{for any}\ \ u\in\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\,\}.$$
Note that for all sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, $R_\epsilon$ is a smooth body of constant width.

Answer (score 16):

Jay P Fillmore, Symmetries of surfaces of constant width, J Differential Geometry 5 (1969) 103-110, says: the curve $$x_1=h\cos\theta-{dh\over d\theta}\sin\theta,\qquad x_2=h\sin\theta+{dh\over d\theta}\cos\theta$$ where $h=a+b\cos3\theta$, $0\lt8b\lt a$, is analytic and of constant width. If we rotate this curve in Euclidean space ${\bf E}^n$ about an $(n-2)$-dimensional axis perpendicular to the line $\theta=0$, we obtain an analytic surface, not a sphere, of constant width in ${\bf E}^n$.

The paper may be available at [https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~fillmore/papers/a.html](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Efillmore/papers/a.html),
https://doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214428822,
https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214428822

Answer (score 8):

Take any odd smooth function h on the unit (d-1)-sphere and take a constant r>0 large enough to ensure that h+r is the support function of a convex body K

(the condition for h+r to be the support function of a smooth convex body whose boundary has positive Gaussian curvature is that the eigenvalues of Hess(h)+(h+r).Id be positive).

This convex body K is of constant width 2r.

Moreover, any smooth convex body with constant width 2r whose boundary has positive Gaussian curvature can be constructed in this way :

If S is a closed convex hypersurface of constant width 2r, then S is the sum of a sphere of radius r with a "projective hedgehog" H whose support function h is the odd part of the support function of S (and which can be regarded as the locus of the middles of S's diameters)." ;

See for instance:

Y. Martinez-Maure, Arch. Math., Vol. 67, 156-163 (1996), page 157.

Answer (score 7):

This relevant paper was just released:

> Howard Resnikoff. "On Curves and Surfaces of Constant Width." Apr. 2015.
> ([arXiv abstract](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.06733).)

> "...we provide a Fourier series-based construction that produces arbitrarily many new surfaces of constant width."

---

![ConstWidth][1]

---

Comment: Also related: Isaac Arelio, Luis Montejano, Deborah Oliveros. "Peabodies of Constant Width." [arXiv abs](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.05769).

Answer (score 6):

Michael Kallay characterized the set of all planar sets with a given width functions: See
M. Kallay, Reconstruction of a plane convex body from the curvature of its boundary. Israel J. Math. 17 (1974), 149–161. and M. Kallay, The extreme bodies in the set of plane convex bodies with a given width function. Israel J. Math. 22 (1975), no. 3-4, 203–207.